# Identifying Webapp Standalone mode in Android

Tags: android, web-applications

I have created a mobile website and use it as a standalone webapp by 'Adding it to Home Screen' on IOS and Android.

I have to apply some class and css only for the standalone mode on IOS and Android. 
In IOS I use

window.navigator.standalone

But this isnt supported in the new Android Chrome which has support for Webapp and add to home screen feature.

Is there any way I can detect if the Site is opened as a Webapp on a Android Device ?

Comment: Sorry about the slightly off-topic comment, but how do you use the 'Add To Home Screen' feature on Android?

Comment: @Darragh If you open the webApp in chrome and check the menu options you have a "Add to Home Screen" Option there.

Comment: Perfect. Just got my hands on an Android device this morning so I know where to look now :) Thanks!